# git log --before="4 months" show me branches that have commits from 3 weeks ago. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: git, shell, command-line, branch, git-log

so I have this snippet that I want to use to filter out branches that doesn't have a certain prefix and that hasn't received any commits in over 3 months so that I can remove them from our remote later on.

```
 for k in $(git branch -r | awk -Forigin !'/\/Prefix1\/|\/prefix2\//'); do
  if [ "$(git log -1 --before="3 month" $k)" ]; then
    echo "$(git log -1 --pretty=format:"%ci, %cr, " $k) $k";
  fi;
done
```

The problem is currently that when I run this I see branches that have received commits 3 weeks ago, 5 months ago, 2 months ago, 1 month ago etc etc and I can't figure out why.

But if I only run: git log --before="4 month" --pretty=format:"%ci, %cr, " It works as intended.

Can anyone give me any guidance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-1` in `git log -1 [filters] $k` will :

- unroll the history of `git log [filters] $k`
- limit this history to its first line

So if a branch has a 3 month old commit in its history (I would guess : any of your branches does), `git log -1 --before="3 month" $k` will always show 1 line -- the first commit in its history that is more than 3 month old.

Your leading `if [ ... ]` condition will always be true.

---

To fix that, you can limit the range of commits to select only the leading commit of each branch :

```
git log --before="3month" $k^..$k
```

---

*[edit]*

Another option (as suggested by user [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) in a comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62573005/86072)) is to list each branch together with the date of its topmost commit, and keep only lines where the date fall below 4 months ago:

```
# in this example I use 'committerdate', you may also use 'authordate' if
# you think it is a better fit for your needs
git branch -r --format="%(committerdate:format:%F)  %(refname:short)" \
    --sort=-committerdate | <... process the list ...>
```

*note* the `--format` option for `git branch` is documented in `git help for-each-ref` (here: [--format flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt---formatltformatgt) and here: [FIELD NAMES section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names)),
if you scroll at the bottom of the FIELD NAMES section, you will find a mention of how to format date fields:

> As a special case for the date-type fields, you may specify a format for the date by adding `:` followed by date format name (see the values the `--date` option to `git-rev-list[1]` takes).

Comment: edited my answer several times, that last suggestion should work.

Comment: Thank you for the pedagogical answer.  This seems to have done the trick! <3

Comment: @Ka_booom Please consider accepting the answer then (and eventually up-voting it), cf. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I'm here again with a follow up question:

Comment: Hi, the best way to do that is to ask a new question ([{Ask Question}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button at top of the page), and paste a link to this current post in your new question.

Comment: @Ka_boom : your comment ends after the `:`, I don't see a question there