# What is the simplest way to display all branches that have not been committed to for more than 6 months?

Tags: bash, git, shell

It seems like 1836 branches exist in one of the company's repos and I've been given a task to first display and then delete all branches that have not been committed to for 6 months.

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325599/delete-all-branches-that-are-more-than-x-days-weeks-old/10325758#10325758) and tried running (with both --until and --before and "month"):

```
#!/bin/bash
branches_to_delete_count=0
for k in $(git branch -a | sed /\*/d); do
  if [ -n "$(git log -1 --before='6 month ago' -s $k)" ]; then
    echo "NOT REALLY DELETING, git branch -D $k"
  fi
  ((branches_to_delete_count=branches_to_delete_count+1))
done
echo "Found $branches_to_delete_count branches to delete!"
```

But to no avail, I get the same number of branches to delete each time which is 1836.

What am I doing wrong? How can I list all branches that haven't been committed for more than 6 months?

Comment: Try `git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname) %(objecttype) %(refname) %(creatordate:unix)' --sort='-creatordate' refs/heads/` and parse the last column as seconds since Unix epoch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git log --before="4 months" show me branches that have commits from 3 weeks ago. what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61585601/git-log-before-4-months-show-me-branches-that-have-commits-from-3-weeks-ago)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why all your branches show up : `git log branch` does not look at branch's *head* only, it looks at its *whole history*.

`git log -1 --before='6 month ago' branch` will :

- unroll the history of `branch`
- keep only commits older than 6 month
- keep the first of these commits

Since (in your company's repo) all branches have a commit that is at least 6 month old in their history, `git log -1 --before='6 month ago' branch` will always show one line.

---

You can instruct `git log` to list only the commits you provide on the command line, and not list their ancestors: [`git log --no-walk`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---no-walksortedunsorted)

The following command will show a one line summary for all branches (local and remote) that have a head commit older than 6 months:

```
git log --oneline --no-walk --before="6 months ago" --branches --remotes
```

You can use the [format option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) to print only the branch names :

```
git log --format="%D" --no-walk --before="6 months ago" --branches --remotes
```

technical note:
if several branches point to the same commit, the above command will print several names separated by a coma, so you could technically see something like:

```
origin/branch1
origin/branch2, origin/branch3
origin/branch4
...
```

for scripting purposes, you may add `... | sed -e 's/, /\n/g'` to be sure to have 1 branch name per line)

---

*note:* updated from my original answer, which suggested to run:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname) %(creatordate)" --sort='-creatordate' refs/heads/
```

and use a second command to check the date

Answer (score -1):

we have not direct get the branch name which has last commit in 6 month ago so we combine git command and make shell script

Here we are passing two git command

- first was `git branch | sed s/^..//` here get branch and remove two space
- second was `git log -1 --before='6 month ago' <branch-name>`

**pass following command in terminal**
copy and past in terminal give branch name

```
for branch in `git branch | sed s/^..//` ; do log=`git log -1 --before='6 month ago' $branch`; if [ ${#log} -gt 0 ] ; then echo $branch; fi; done
```

**this is shell script along with git command same as above**

save shell script with `test.sh`,change mode `chmod +x test.sh` then run `bash test.sh`

```
month=6 #check how many year ago
for branch in `git branch | sed s/^..//`  #get branch one by one 
do
  log=`git log -1 --before='%s month ago'$month $branch` #getting log of the branch last commit base on month
  if [ ${#log} -gt 0 ] #check if  log has output then it has branch commit before specify month ago 
  then 
      echo $branch  # print branch name which is in our project
  fi
done
```

let me know does it work or not

Comment: This code has the same bug as the OP : it will list all branches.